# Rails 3 + action mailer - Cannot loop to send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

A user can create an object, and he has followers that I want to alert when he creates this object.

**controller:**

```
if @project.save
  format.html { redirect_to(@project, :notice => 'Project was successfully created.') }
  format.xml  { render :xml => @project, :status => :created, :location => @project }
  # Send a notification to project owner's followers :
  UserMailer.new_project(@project).deliver
else
  ...
```

**user_mailer.rb:**

```
def new_project(project)
    @url  = "http://localhost:3000/"
    @project = project
    # For each of project owner's follower, send an email notification
    @followers = project.owner.followers.all
    @followers.each do |f|
        @u = User.find(f.follower)
        mail(   :to => @u.email,
            :from => '"Beatrix Kiddo" <beatrix@example.com>',
            :subject => "#{project.owner.name} created a new project")
    end
end
```

Testing with a user that has 2 followers:
`User.find(1).followers.count = 2`

`Follower.follower` is the `id` of the user who's following.

**Only 1 email is sent to the 1st follower, and the 2nd doesn't receive anything - what's wrong?**

**[SOLVED]** => the `.deliver` method simply doesn't support multiple messages. Thx [DR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23368/dr)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

ActionMailer does not support sending multiple messages with one `deliver` call.
You have to move the loop outside of the `new_project` method:

Instead of

```
UserMailer.new_project(@project).deliver
```

try this:

```
@followers = @project.owner.followers.all
@followers.each do |f|
    UserMailer.new_project(@project, f).deliver
end
```

The `new_project` method then could look like this:

```
def new_project(project, follower)
    @u = User.find(f.follower)
    mail(:to => @u.email,
         :from => '"Beatrix Kiddo" <beatrix@example.com>',
         :subject => "#{project.owner.name} created a new project")
end
```

Comment: Great, working just fine ---
Didn't know the **deliver** method doesn't support multiple messages --- Thx very much !

Comment: As an aide memoire it's worth thinking about mailers as controllers and the mail method as rendering a view. Controllers can only render once.

Answer (score 6):

You can also move the .deliver call into your `new_project` method. This works for me using Rails 3:

```
def new_project(project)
  # ...
  @followers.each do |f|
    # ...
    mail(:to => @u.email,
         :from => '"Beatrix Kiddo" <beatrix@example.com>',
         :subject => "#{project.owner.name} created a new project").deliver
  end
end
```

To send the mails, you would use

```
if @project.save
   # ...
   UserMailer.new_project(@project)
else
   # ...
end
```