# Rails Actionmailer to email specific group of users based on User attribute being included in array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I have a **Document** model with a string column **access** and a **User** model with a string column **team**. In a **Document** I can enter an array of items for **access** such as "staff, sales, manager". Meanwhile, a **User** has only **one** item under **team**.

I am trying to send emails to specific Users based on whether or not for each **user.team** is included in the array for **Document.access**.

**For example** if `Document.access = "sales, management"`, only Users with `team = "sales" or team = "management"` will be sent the email. Other Users such as team = "accounting" would not.

---

#### Update:

From what I gather on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296687/rails-3-action-mailer-cannot-loop-to-send-emails), It would appear ActionMailer cannot loop, so I have modified my document_observer. Now that I moved the loop portion out of the mailer, **user.email** is erroring out with

`undefined method 'user' for`

If I stick in a string like **'joe@net.com'** the proper number of emails go out, so that part seems to work. Now it is a matter of passing the right email addresses to the message.

Relevant code from my document_observer below:

```
 def after_save(model)
   @users = User.all
   @users.each do |user|
     if model.access.include? user.team
       MultiMailer.doc_notification(model).deliver
     end
   end  
 end
```

Relevant code from mailer. How do I pass on **user.email** for each email?

```
def doc_notification(document)
  mail(:to => 'joe@net.com')
end
```

---

#### Latest Update:

Ok, I just switched a couple of lines to

```
MultiMailer.doc_notification(user).deliver
```

and

```
def doc_notification(user)
```

So now the email goes out to each of the right users, but it appears I am just reversing the problem above and trading unknown user for unknown document. The email needs to reference the URL for the document that was just updated..

**I should also mention that there is no association between Document and User.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### The Answer

From the **document_observer**

```
def after_save(model)
  @users = User.all
  @users.each do |user|
    if model.access.include? user.team
      MultiMailer.doc_notification(model, user).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

From the **mailer**

```
def doc_notification(document, user)
  @document = document
  mail(:to => user.email)
end
```

**Credit goes to a very nice [Nathaniel Talbott](http://www.meetup.com/raleighrb/members/259885/) of Triangle Ruby Brigade who answered my question in person.** I guess it helps to get out the house sometimes.