# rails call method that should send email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, methods, parameter-passing, parameters

So, I have an index page with grid of some students. With a button I would call an email method to send an email at all student in `@students = Student.all`

How to call the method ?

The params for the method is @students, is it right ?

```
<%= link_to 'Email', send_to_student_path(@students) %>
```

As I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518352/rails-actionmailer-to-email-specific-group-of-users-based-on-user-attribute-bein)

StudentController.rb

```
  def send_to_student()
   #binding.pry
   @students.each do |student|
     StudentMailer.email_recall(student).deliver
    end
  end
```

And the Mailer :

```
class StudentMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    def email_recall(student)
        @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
        mail(to: @student.email, 
            from: current_user.email,
            subject: 'Valid your datas') 

    end
end
```

In routes.rb I have :

```
resources :students do 

    member do
        post :send_to_student
    end
end
```

First question : 
How can I pass id of each student from @students = Student.all in the method param ?

Second question :
How to call the `send_to_student` method in the right way ?

Many thanks in advance

Nicolas

Comment: I'm sorry, it's @students = Student.all

Answer (score 0):

1) The way you're using it, you'd pass the ID through the route, like: `students/:id/send` - you can read more about [member routing on the Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions). This will set a parameter of `params[:id]`, which you can use in your action

Alternatively, if you're looking to send a message to all students, you can just use the controller function I created below:

---

2) I think you can typically use a [Model Method](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) for this. This is where you put a function in the model, cleaning up your controller

I don't know if it will work with the mailer, but I'd try this:

```
  #app/controllers/students_controller.rb
  def index
      @students = Student.all
      Student.send_to_students(@students)
  end

  #app/models/student.rb
  def self.send_to_student(students)
      students ||= self.all # -> not sure about the self.all call
      students.each do |student|
          StudentMailer.email_recall(student).deliver
      end
  end
```