# Why iterating through user doesn't work inside mailer method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, delayed-job

I have a controller action that creates a reminder, I'm passing `@event` and `@users` to go through the users and check if they have checked the check box for reminder, by default I have set it to True.

This is suppose to check for me which user wants to get an email, and send them the email in the mailer, however it doesn't work that way. It clear the queue without sending the email.

```
def create
        ReminderMailer.delay(queue: "#{@event.name}_letter", run_at: 1.minutes.from_now).events_reminder(@event,@users)

end
```

In my mailer I have this:

```
def events_reminder(event,users)
    @event =  event
    @users = users
    users.each do |user|
          if user.eventReminder == true
            mail to: user.email, subject: "Reminder"
          end
    end 
end
```

It creates the queue, but it doesn't send the emails.

Am I facing the problem that this user is getting ?

[Rails 3 + action mailer - Cannot loop to send emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296687/rails-3-action-mailer-cannot-loop-to-send-emails)

Comment: What do you get when you output `users` to the console from `events_reminder`? Also it doesn't look like you're setting either `@event` or `@users` in your `create` method in your controller.

Comment: @tirdadc I have set both  `@event` or `@users` in my create method. and `users` does print out all the users listed when I look at my delayed job log.

Answer (score 0):

After 7 days :/! Found the solution in the documentation... It's true when they say RTFM :)!

Here is the solution:

> 2.3.3 Sending Email To Multiple Recipients
>
> It is possible to send email to one or more recipients in one email
>   (e.g., informing all admins of a new signup) by setting the list of
>   emails to the :to key. The list of emails can be an array of email
>   addresses or a single string with the addresses separated by commas.

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default to: Proc.new { Admin.pluck(:email) },
          from: 'notification@example.com'

  def new_registration(user)
    @user = user
    mail(subject: "New User Signup: #{@user.email}")
  end
end
```

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks